# delete records from foreign-key constraint in table2 which does have primary key in table1

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose Table1 has

```
wordid col2
 1     x
 2     y
 3     x
```

Now table2 has

```
wordid col3
  1    a
  2    b
  3    c
  4    d
```

The "wordid" column in the "table1" table is the PRIMARY KEY in the "table1" table.

The "wordid" column in the "table2" table is a FOREIGN KEY in the "table2" table.

I want to delete all records in "table2" that are not bound to any constraint. ( here row with wordid "4" needs to be deleted)

Comment: You can't have wordid=4 in table2 as it a FK.

Comment: I had a record wordid=4 in table1 which i have deleted. Now i want to remove the records from table2.

Comment: You can use cascading delete.

Comment: That would delete wordid=1,2,3 also .. which is not the motive

Comment: I need to find the row which are not bound to frng key constraints and remove them from table2

Comment: It deletes only related data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't have the FK set up yet or aren't enforcing integrity?

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE wordid NOT IN
( SELECT wordid FROM table1 )
```

Like Hamlet suggested in the comments, you should be using `ON DELETE CASCADE` in the FK and enforcing FK integrity.

Comment: @KaNcH you have something wrong with your foreign key.  Did you do it backwards?  It looks like you have the foreign key on table1 referencing table2 when according to your example, it should be the other way around.